# Multiple Assertions in MSTest

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, mstest

I am developing a C# based Selenium .Net application testing suite using MSTest and am in fairly later stages of the development. I now feel the need to implement multiple assertions for a test case. As per my research, multiple assertions are not available in MSTest and I dont have the time to convert to Nunit. I would have to learn the infrastructure of Nunit all over again and it will be extremely time taking. Is there any way to have a similar functionality in MSTest.

My use case is pretty similar to verifying the properties of a user profile. For example:

```
Assert.Equal("Expected Value", firstName);
Assert.Equal("Expected Value", lastName);
Assert.Equal("Expected Value", country);
```

Now if the first assertion fails, I won't be able to assert rest of the values. Is there any way I can do this without going for Nunit?

Comment: You could assert on a tuple like `Assert.Equal(("FN", "LN", "CT"), (firstName, lastName, country));`

Comment: Try with Soft Assert

Comment: Thank you so much for directing me towards Soft Assertions. I modified the example in this article to meet my needs and it works like a charm!: https://automationrhapsody.com/soft-assertions-c-unit-testing-frameworks-mstest-nunit-xunit-net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FluentAssertions nuget package which provides many other assertions which are not in mstest.

If you are using mstestv2 you can use Extending MSTest assertions feature to customize your assertions and re-use it. [Refer this](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/02/extending-assert-in-mstest.html)